# Auto height in WPF usercontrol

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout

Suppose I have the following XAML.

How can I achieve that outermost `Button` has such height so that text from `TextBlock` is completely visible?

```
<StackPanel>
        <Button HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Width="100" >
            <DockPanel >
                <CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="X" />                
                <TextBlock >
  some very long text some very long textsome very long textsome very long textsome very long text
                </TextBlock>
            </DockPanel>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `TextBlock.TextWrapping` to `Wrap` so it will wrap the text to a new line when it reaches the edge of the allowed space

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" 
           Text="some very long text some very long textsome very long textsome very long textsome very long text" />
```

Comment: yay! I knew it would be simple.

Answer (score 0):

Add another stack panel

```
<StackPanel>
        <Button HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Width="auto" >
            <DockPanel>
                <CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="x" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                    <TextBlock Text="some very long text some very long textsome very long textsome very long textsome very long text" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DockPanel>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
```